# Alternative to PASS or FAIL in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework

Sometimes a test fails because of infrastructure failures, for example a network outage that does not indicate a regression.  Is there any alternative in robotframework to PASS / FAIL?  Something like ERROR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robot Framework offers only PASS or FAIL, nothing like ERROR. 
I can see 2 strategies though to handle those intermittent problems (that most of us are facing).

1) use the ["wait until keywords succeeds"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds) keyword. For example, if you have to do a GET via REST on a remote server that could be unreachable for some network reason, then instead of

```
Get  MyURL
```

you could do

```
wait until keywords succeeds  Get  http://example.com
```

and even better option would be to create a custom keyword for that

```
*** keywords ***
Get_until_succeeds
[Arguments]  ${url}
  wait until keywords succeeds  Get  ${url}
```

So then you just have to call:

```
Get_until_succeeds  http://example.com
```

2) use the ["--rerunfailed"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#re-executing-failed-test-cases) option or Robot Framework that allows you to re-run the tests that failed. The way to use it is to first launch your suite the usual way:

```
pybot tests
```

And then give the output.xml of the previous execution as input of another round:

```
pybot --rerunfailed output.xml tests
```

(you can then merge the 2 reports and get a single nice report)